# autologin in authlogic Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have added auhlogic in my Rails app to authenticate users. I have also included the code from the [Reset password tutorial](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/) . All of it works, the only issue I have is that once a user registers he gets automatically logged in.

Anyone worked with authlogic, what would be the best & fastest way to disable the autologin after the registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After registration save succeeds,

```
session = UserSession.find
session.destroy if session
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use #save_without_session_maintenance:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save_without_session_maintenance
```

Answer (score 6):

If you will use this way:

> After registration save succeeds,

```
 session = UserSession.find  
 session.destroy if session
```

You probably can loss your Admin session, who perhaps adding the user.
So, the better way will be is just to add some options to your model **user.rb**:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.maintain_sessions = false
    #for more options check the AuthLogic documentation
end
```

Now it should work.

Comment: That would work but will also permanently disable the maintain sessions functionality. So Ptico's answer is better. It disables this only for the needed request.